# Finding multiplicative inverses

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, inverse, congruences

Find the multiplicative inverses,if they exist for:(i)12 mod 15 (ii)12 mod 13; (if not, explain why they do not exist)

Can someone help me finish this? The first one doesn't have an inverse, because gcd(12, 15) is not 1, right? or Did I get it wrong?

Will appreciate pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: You're right. An integer $a$ has a multiplicative inverse in modulo $b$ if and only if $gcd(a,b)=1$

Comment: how about the 12 mod 13? i'm not used to having just the mod without the ≡. Do i have to do something first before I continue?

Comment: @JackilynJose Why don't you apply the same argument as in the first case?

Answer (score 1):

$12$ does not have an inverse modulo $15$ since $\gcd(12,15) \ne 1$.

Since $12 \equiv -1 \pmod{13}$, we have $12^2 \equiv (-1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$ so $12$ is its own inverse modulo $13$. More generally, $n-1$ is always its own inverse modulo $n$ because $n-1 \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$.

Comment: In 12 ≡ -1(mod 13), how did you get the -1?

Comment: $12-(-1)$ is a $13$ multiple @JackilynJose

Comment: It's worth nothing that more generally, one can use the extended Euclidean algorithm to find inverses mod $n$